# Use of {{ block }} inside {{ define }} in helm templates

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Can someone explain (or point to good explanation) on the use of {{ block }} inside {{ define }} in helm templates? I’m going nuts trying to find good example or clear explanation - i’m not seeing the difference using that vs just {{ define }} alone

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `{{ block }}` in a Helm template.

The [Go text/template documentation](https://godoc.org/text/template) says of `block`:

> The typical use is to define a set of root templates that are then customized by redefining the block templates within.

That would make more sense if you had something like a base HTML page layout you were reusing in several places and could customize it by redefining the content.  Helm templates tend to just not have that setup.  Even though the Kubernetes YAML files are pretty repetitive, things like the number and kind of objects are highly variable even across similar-looking charts.

Comment: Yeah, from what I've seen, no one seems to make use of blocks. Was just wondering what was different about them - if there is some functionality - though it seems like its a way to make more granular areas you can override inside an define - otherwise, nothing special about them